# If I have a route with multiple params, how can i get both params chained?

Tags: javascript, express, parameters, url-routing

This is how I thought it could be done and I am not getting the expected results.

```
router.param('param_1', function(req, res, next, param){
   req.param_1 = param;
   next();
});

router.param('param_2', function(req, res, next, param){
   req.param_1.param_2 = param;
   next();
});

router.get(':param_1/urlstuff/:param_2', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.param_1);
    console.log(req.param_1.param_2);
    res.send('done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I assume the value as an object but it was a string.

if we declare an object first and assign the value to a property of it and later to the request object, in the child parameter we will be able to chain the second value.

```
router.param('param_1', function(req, res, next, param){
   var param_1 = {};

   param_1.value = param;    

   req.param_1 = param_1;
   next();
});

router.param('param_2', function(req, res, next, param){
   req.param_1.param_2 = param;
   next();
});

router.get(':param_1/urlstuff/:param_2', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.param_1); // logs an object with value property and param_2 string value.
   console.log(req.param_1.param_2); // logs param_2 string value
   res.send('done');
});
```